# Warning: require_once(modules/Home/metadata/popupdefs.php)

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In SugarCRM 6.2.x I receive the below error, I reinstalled but the same thing. Searched Google, but couldn't find the answer.

> Warning: require_once(modules/Home/metadata/popupdefs.php)
>
> [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/spsbiz/public_html/include/Popups/Popup_picker.php
>   on line 65
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'modules/Home/metadata/popupdefs.php'
>
> (include_path='/home/spsbiz/public_html:/home/spsbiz/public_html/include/..:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in /home/spsbiz/public_html/include/Popups/Popup_picker.php on line 65

The folder "modules/Home/metadata" does not exist.

It happens when I try to assign a User to a Person in a custom module with the field 'Assigned User'.

Comment: I've just started to get this error????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the file doesn't exist and it shouldn't because i don't see a reason why should there be a popupdefs definition for a Home module? You never relate anything to it and so it doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the name of 'Assigned to'? If you have, all that you need is to delete the array 'assigned_user_id' in `custom\modulebuilder\packages\name_of_your_system\modules\module_name\` (This helps for adding Assigned User).

But the error is fixed by this:
https://github.com/pribeiro42/SuiteCRM/commit/a64e599c9c7c628d14bb1e9e1fe41f2c1ce1a47f